# Difference in AWS Cloudformation stack when updating via console to updating with same json via CLI

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-cli

I have an existing AWS stack and can update manually via console using Cloud Formation with no issues.

via the GUI, I can upload stack json file and deploy with only changes made to template updated or returns the correct output if no changes are included. There are also many default values already updated as parameters and defined within the json.

Error \

My issue is when I run the same update via the CLI using example code below

```
aws cloudformation update-stack  --stack-name $stackname  --template-url https://s3-myregion.amazonaws.com/mybucket --parameters ParameterKey=MasterUsername,UsePreviousValue=true ParameterKey=MasterUserPassword,UsePreviousValue=true --capabilities CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM
```

This begins to update the stack but starts to amend RDS database, create a new EC2 instance already created,  re-create a new vpn and customer gateway that already exists. these values are not defaulted within the UI as parameters other than EC2 instance ami when updating via the GUI.

I am looking to move manual updates via gui to an automated process via a build type server.

Do I need to use like below in command

--use-previous-template

or do I need to set for all resources/Parameters, UsePreviousValue=true

FYI: I have tested on smaller stack with only an EC2 instance and security group and this updates fine without having to re-create resources.

Comment: Could this be metadata related ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to sort this , the changes were in the default values for ami and vpn BGP default values.

I was able to find this by creating change set from within the CLI and examining the changes more clearly.
once these were updated both ui and cli matched. happy days

Answer (score 0):

Is there a ‘$’ missing from the second ‘$true’?

Comment: ive amended , sorry typo ,does not affect code as these resources not affected when updating.